# Включение экрана блокировки

Tags: android, мобильная-разработка

Как включить экран блокировки андроид при приходе уведомления Notification? Может вопрос глупый но ничего полезноо не нашел

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался, может кому полезно будет. `

`

```
public  class WakeLocker {
    private  PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    private Context context;

    public WakeLocker(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public  void On() {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
        PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
        PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "WakeLock");
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    public  void Off() {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release(); wakeLock = null;
    }
}
```